# Замена content в компоненте приложения reactjs

Tags: css3, reactjs

Есть компонент:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

    const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text }) => (
      <li className="ui-state-default">
        {text}

        <span className="todo-item fa fa-square-o" aria-hidden="true" title="Toggle" onClick={onClick}
        style={{ content: completed ? '"\f046"' : '"\f096"' }}></span>

      </li>
    )

    Todo.propTypes = {
      onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
      text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }

    export default Todo
```

Он должен при клике на квадратик заменить его на чекед-квадратик и наоборот. 
Что нужно изменить здесь `style={{ content: completed ? '"\f046"' : '"\f096"' }}`, чтобы менялась картинка? Если я использую просто графические иконки .png и вместо `content` – `background`, то всё работает.

Comment: Уточняю: применить content можно только к псевдоэлементу content::before. Но символы :: вызывают синтаксическую ошибку. Как записать строку на TypeScript, если это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно по Вашему комментарию – используйте кавычки вокруг `::before`:

```
{ '::before': { content: completed ? '"\f046"' : '"\f096"' }}
```

---

А почему бы не изменять содержимое самого `span`?

Либо добавлять `checked` в `className`, а в css уже использовать что-то типа

```
todo-item.checked::before {
    content: "\f046"
}

todo-item::before {
    content: "\f096"
}
```